# If the half life of Caffeine is ~6 hours, why do people consider it ineffective after its half-life?

Tags: pharmacology

Caffeine [has a half-life of ~ 6 hours in the body](http://ajcp.oxfordjournals.org/content/73/3/390.long).

So assuming you take 200mg of caffeine, after 6 hours there should still be 100mg of caffeine in your body.

Then why is it generally said that after 6 hours caffeines effect should wear off? Shouldn't it only be diminished since there is still 100mg of caffeine in your body?

Comment: You need to consider what concentration of caffeine within the body will have biological effects. That is, you could have 1 picogram of caffeine on your body but you may be well below the threshold needed to have a biologic effect.

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh Yeah, but it's generally stated that after 6 hours regardless of dosage that caffeine "wears off", so technically my 200mg original dose becomes ineffective even though after its half life I'd still have 100mg (which is definitely enough to have biological effects?)

Comment: where are you reading that - what source?